# C#: Why is the final value for x different to the value outside the for loop?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double x;
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

My code prints out this as a result of the for loop:
0
1
2
3
4

and the

```
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

which is outside the loop prints the value 5. Why is it incrementing x by 1 outside the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the `for` is still being executed on the 5th time.
 But it doesn't enter it since `x<5` is being evaluated to `false`.
That is why in most cases a variable that has been defined inside a `for` loop isn't going to be used after it.

Comment: Ah yes now I see. Thanks to everyone you all had the same answer. So we can assume that a for loop will overwrite the saved location of the double x each time it iterates? i.e. It is not a temporary saved location it is permanent for the double x?

Comment: If I understand what you meant, then yes. X is not a local variable in the scope of the for loop. It can be referenced and change everywhere in main.

Comment: That is what I mean and that answers the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the last cycle x equals to 5 because it was icremented but didn't pass the check `x<5`. That's why it prints 5 in the end.

I found a similar [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx). I adapted the explanation to your example.

> 1. First, the initial value of variable i is established. This step happens only once, regardless of how many times the loop repeats. You
>      can think of this initialization as happening outside the looping
>      process.
> 2. To evaluate the condition `i < 5`, the value of `i` is compared to `5`.
>
>    - If `i` is less than `5`, the condition evaluates to true, and the
>        following actions occur: The `Console.WriteLine` statement in the body
>        of the loop displays the value of `i`. **The value of i is incremented
>        by `1`.** The loop returns to the start of step 2 to evaluate the
>        condition again.
>    - If i is greater than or equal to `5`, the condition
>        evaluates to false, and you exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The loop increments x each iteration, and breaks out only when it is not < 5. Hence to break out of the loop it must logically be 5.

Answer (score 0):

The value was already increased to 5 the memory hold at last. And no any further check was made outside the loop